# What kind of motion does a quadratic position time graph represent?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

When I make a function to represent an object's position at intervals of two seconds, and it is parabolic, *for example* $f(x)=\dfrac{5x^2}{2}$ with the following points:

$ \text{seconds} \ \ \text{metre}  $

$  0       \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \   0  $

$  2       \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \   10 $

$  4      \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \   40  $

$  6       \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \   90  $

What does this graph represent? I think it has to do with acceleration? I'm not exactly confident here, because it doesn't follow the standard form where you see acceleration written in explicitly.
It isn't velocity... because velocity is linear.  I've confused myself...

Comment: think again ....

Comment: Please note that we do not answer homework-like question on SE. Please ask a conceptional question.

Comment: I dont see why people believe this is a homework like question. This aint about solving a math equation. Its about making sense of a math equation when applied to physics. What those x,y,x means in physics.

Answer (score 1):

You have graphed position s as a function of time: $s(t) $in Physics notation.
But you call time $t$ your independent variable $x$, and your $f$ refers to the mathematical shape of the function rather than the resulting Physical quantity position $s$, which is the dependent variable, a.k.a. $ y$ in maths.

The derivative with respect to t would be the velocity $v(t) = 5t$, a straight line.
The second derivative would be the constant change of velocity, i.e. the acceleration $a(t) = 5$

You "get" only what you draw in the first place (you said it: position).
From there, it depends on what you do next with it (derivation, looking for zeros etc.) to get some other information.

And once you know that the acceleration $a(t)$ doesn't actually depend on the time here, you can define the constant a = 5 to rewrite $s(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2$ or with your variables $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}ax^2$ which should look familiar.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I tried an honnest response, and I do not have the credits to comment on OP. Why can't you just ignore the answer if you are not interested on your level of understanding? (btw, as a secondary school teacher I can see the conceptional problem)

Comment: Hello Sir.I didn't downvote . I am no expert but according to current site policy answering hw question encourages more people to ask more homework question.

Comment: Thanks, but this is clearly not a homework problem but about trying to make sense of functions in Physics. Or do they mean by "homework" any conceptional struggle at the secondary school level? OP doesn't ask to solve a specific problem, but wants to know where the kinematic quantities go in a mathematically stated function. And I know from experience that translating from maths f(x) to Physics s(t) is a common problem. People should be more tolerant, for at that level it is very hard to search for similar questions in SE.

Comment: Frank S., anyone can downvote anonymously for any reason and there's practically nothing you can do about that.  As a rule, I don't give anonymous downvotes a second thought.

Comment: This is even a hot question on meta(a question of similar type) -https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12972/why-was-this-answer-deleted-as-a-complete-answer-to-a-homework-question?cb=1

Comment: @FrankS. Sir even if it isn't the site refrain people from giving complete answer to hw like problem ex- "The derivative with respect to t would be the velocity v(t)=5t, a straight line. The second derivative would be the constant change of velocity, i.e. the acceleration a(t)=5." Clearing underlying concept is fine.

Comment: You are right, @Bhavay, but I needed the derivatives to make clear how the other quantities come into play, since I suspect that OP thought that plotting the graph of "accelerated position" equals to plotting acceleration itself. At that level, they do not know many functions, and so quadratic, linear, constant become synonymous with position, velocity, and acceleration - only that quadratic is also associated with accelerated, hence the confusion. You need to start somewhere, that is why we stick to the concrete example at that level, and say what goes where, rather than abstract paraphrasing

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to ask what it means that your object's position versus time function is second order.

So to answer in general terms, when your position versus time has a first order relationship
$ f(x) = vx + c $ or $ s(t) = vt + c $
where c is the starting position at $t=0$
it means the object is moving at constant speed $v$
away from starting position $c$

When you get a second order equation
$ f(x) = ax^2 + vx + c $ or $ s(t) = at^2 + vt + c $
it means that your object is moving at constant acceleration $a$ away from starting point $c$ where the initial speed was $v$.

So in your example the object is moving at constant acceleration of $2.5 \;\text{m/s}^2$  from an initial position of $0\;\text{m}$ and starting speed of $0\;\text{m/s}$

Note that this is only true when you're working with simplified cases where an object is moving in a straight line, when you start working with more dimentions equations get trickier.

Comment: @Ken Thanks for the edit. Went away to go check how to do the formatting (never used MatJax) got back and couldn't edit. The only thing you did wrong was putting text brackets in the wrong place, which changed the units of acceleration to m/s but easy fix.